# Handling error in WSTP program C/C++

Tags: warning-messages, interoperability, message-coding, c++

I have a program, written in C++, which uses [WSTP](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html) to communicate with *Mathematica* 10 (i.e., linked using `Install["name_program"]`).

How should my code report an internal error? I've read through the WRI docs on [Error and Interrupt Handling](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ErrorAndInterruptHandling.html), but unfortunately they only talk about an instance where there are problems with the connection between the program and *Mathematica*, which doesn't apply to my case.

Example:

```cpp
extern "C" int get_number(int param)
{
    try
    {
        //calculate result
        return result;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //What should be here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Since c does not use exceptions, WSTP does not, so the `Try`/`Catch` block is not useful, *unless* you are throwing your own errors. So, you put whatever you want. More specifically, each put/get function returns a `bool` (actually an `int`, but 0 is `False`, anything else is `True`) indicating if it has succeeded, and if it returns false, you handle it then. Your handling it could be `Throw` to a common error handler, but whether or not that is useful is for you to decide.

Comment: My suggestion is to report errors through return values, then have a Mathematica-side function that parses the return value and does what is necessary.  For this, it's better to use the `Manual` return type in MathLink and return values explicitly.  Then you'll have the option of returning e.g. `$Failed` (a symbol) *or* a number, or whatever expression you like.  Generally: don't try to do too much in C, it's too much work.  Make the C side as simple as you can and have a Mathematica side wrapper to handle more complex situations such as error reporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl; dr**  Report errors through return values.  MathLink programs can return any Mathematica expression they like which makes structured error handling possible.

---

It looks like you have a function that returns integers with a template like

```
:Begin:
:Function:      get_number
:Pattern:       getNumber[x_Integer]
:Arguments:     {x}
:ArgumentTypes: {Integer32}
:ReturnType:    Integer32
:End:
```

Use a `Manual` return type instead:

```
:Begin:
:Function:      get_number
:Pattern:       getNumber[x_Integer]
:Arguments:     {x}
:ArgumentTypes: {Integer32}
:ReturnType:    Manual
:End:
```

Then you can return any expression you like, not just integers:

```c
void get_number(int param) {
    ...
    if (success)
        MLPutInteger32(stdlink, result);
    else
        MLPutSymbol(stdlink, "$Failed");
}
```

You can return a symbol such as `$Failed` or a compound expression with some information about the error, e.g. `` myPackage`myError[12, "this is an error"] ``.

Then instead of exposing `getNumber` on the Mathematica side to the user, create a wrapper for it that will handle the return values with pattern matching and whatever is needed on errors, e.g. issue a [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Message.html).